# How to encrypt a password in cakephp 2.x version

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hello everyone i am using cakephp 2.x, as i am new to here, i need to encrypt my password before it stores to database

User.ctp :  I am posting like this to post

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password','label'=>false,'div'=>false,'class'=>'form-control','id'=>'password'));
?>
```

Controller:

```
public function setting()
{

    $this->layout='setting_template';
    if($this->Session->read('username')==""){

        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'user_login'));

    }
    elseif ($this->Session->read('username') == "admin" )
    {

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $this->data['password'] = encrypt($this->data ['password']);

            if ($this->Login->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'setting'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try  again.');
            }
            }
        $opp=$this->Login->find('all');
        $this->set('login',$opp);

    }
    else{

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Permission Denied');    </script>";
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

    }

}
```

Login controller:

```
public function login()
{
$this->layout='login_template';
if($this->data)
{
$this->Session->write('id',$this->data['Login']['id'] );
$results = $this->Login->find('first',array('conditions' =>  array('Login.password' => $this->data['Login']['password'],'Login.username'  => $this->data['Login']['username'])));
$this->Session->write('name',$results['Login']['name']);
if ($results['Login']['id'])
 {
 $this->Session->write($this->data['Login']['username'].','. $this->data['Login']['password']);
   $this->Session->write('username',$this->data['Login']['username']);
   $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
   }
  else
  {
   $this->Session->setFlash("error");
 }
}
```

How can i encrypt the password file and also how can use the Model

Comment: Manohar Khadka's answer
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067966/2688498) is a good one. However I would advise to use the word hash instead of encrypt. Passwords should never be saved in a form that it can be retrieved again

Comment: yeah Manohar khadka's answer is good, but when i use hash it the password works with only the hashed one not with real one.(Eg:-- passowrd: hello123 hashed:: 9ee143147311a6ddd3b74b830674c887ba972b49dab4d826d0b7a3e334a789e) if i enter hello123 it's not logging in if enter hashed only it's getting logged in @Nicholas

Comment: It sounds like you're comparing the password to the hash, which will (presumably) never work. You need to compare the hash of the password from the login attempt with the user's stored password hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using `CakePhp` go with framework's best practices.

> When creating new user records you can hash a password in the
>   beforeSave callback of your model using appropriate password hasher
>   class:

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {
   public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
 }
```

You don’t need to hash passwords before calling `$this->Auth->login()`. The various authentication objects will hash passwords individually.

If you are using different model than `User` for authentication you need to define that in AppController. In your Case you need to do something like this in AppController:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Login')
);
```

If you wish to hash your password, try this:

```
$hashedPassword = AuthComponent::password('original_password');
```

See Here :[Cakephp Password Hashing](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords).

Comment: there is an error, the password is getting hashed but when i try to login it is showing error, it is logging in with only when we enter the password that is hashed. and please specify the decryption method to .

Comment: Still having error ? Do you have 'password' field on database ? See here if you use other fields.. https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: yes in database i am having the password field,as i said you i can able to login with the password which is hashed and with the original one, if enter the password it shows wrong password if i enter the hashed one it's getting logged in.

Comment: how is your components array in AppController ? where did you put the above code ?

Comment: i have placed your code in my model. and i have added my login controller also with it you can check that above

Comment: i hope you are not getting my point, as i have hashed my password before it saves, so i when i am validating (i mean logging in) it's not working with password(eg: hello is my password with hash i get like this 9ee143147311a6ddd3b74b830674c887ba972b49dab4d826d0b7a3e334a7‌​89e) so when i enter hello it is saying wrong password, when i enter hashed one it's working. so need to hash it before it validates

Comment: I am already clearly understood what you are saying..You don't need to hash it before validation.. Just try the updated answer.. Cakephp convention is there for you.

Comment: "and please specify the decryption method to"
Hashes, by definition, have no decryption method. You're advised to compare hashes rather than storing any retrievable form of the user's password to compare in plaintext with the password entered in a login attempt.