# How to decrypt the hashed password in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

model

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class AppModel extends Model {
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
   if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
   $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha1'));
       $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
       $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
       );
   }
   return true;
 }
```

so when i use it is hashing the password but when i try to login, instead of original password, i have to use the hashed one. Then only it's getting logged in.

Here i have asked how to encrypt but it is not helping in logging in  [How to encrypt a password in cakephp 2.x version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067691/)

Comment: A hash of a password can't be decrypted since it's not a decryption. What you do is that you hash the password before making the check if it's a correct password. So you take a normal text input and then before you make the password validation you hash the input with the same hash cridentials as you did when you saved the password.

Answer (score 1):

When logging in with a password that is stored as a hash in the database you need to apply the same hash method to the input password and compare that with the one stored in the database:-

```
// Has the password supplied via the login form.
$inputHashedPassword = (new SimplePasswordHasher(['hashType' => 'sha1']))->hash($inputPassword);
// Compare hashed input with hashed password from the database.
if ($inputHashedPassword === $storedHashedPassword) {
    // Login
}
```

The point of hashing passwords is that it can't be decrypted so only the person who entered the password originally should know its original value. So the only way of checking passwords is to check the hashed values.

Comment: is there is any other way in encrypting the password, but in laravel everything is defined. like that is there anything

Comment: @drmonkeyninja One should however use **[`AbstractPasswordHasher::check()`](https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-AbstractPasswordHasher.html#_check)** for doing that. And of course the authentication component would do that automatically, ie the OP probably hasn't set that up (correctly).